# Login to Azure Container Registry in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I am unable to follow the documentation for logging into my container registry in Azure using the task "DockerCompose@0".

The documentation suggests to use:

```
variables:
  azureContainerRegistry: Contoso.azurecr.io
  azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Contoso
steps:
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: Container registry login
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
    azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
```

Where *azureSubscriptionEndpoint* is the name of the Service Connection for ARM.

I used the following pipeline:

```
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604

variables:
  azureContainerRegistry: <ACRName>.azurecr.io
  azureSubscriptionEndpoint: <SubscriptionName> (<SubscriptionID>)

steps:

  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: Container registry login
    inputs:
      containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
      azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)

  - task: DockerCompose@0
    inputs:
      containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"<ACRName>.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<ACRName>"}'
      dockerComposeFile: '<Path>/docker-compose.yml'
      action: 'Build services'

  - task: DockerCompose@0
    inputs:
      containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"<ACRName>.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<ACRName>"}'
      dockerComposeFile: '<Path>/docker-compose.yml'
      action: 'Push services'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: "Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: <Path>
      Contents: '**\docker-compose.yml'
      TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish Artifact: drop"
```

However, I am receiving following error in my pipeline:

```
##[error]Input required: dockerComposeCommand
```

for the the first task (*Container registry login*).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't need the login step from your build, docker tasks handle Auth using azure subscription endpoint if it is pre configured, if not - give your service principal permissions to acrpush.

Comment: You are correct. I did actually suspect that, but my reference to the Container Registry (azureContainerRegistry) in the 2nd and 3rd task action for build and push does not work as expected. So I changed it to <ACRName>.azurecr.io and now everything works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You misinterpret the documentation. **You don't need a separate login step**, you have to specify the login information on each DockerCompose Task you are using.

Comment: i guess the same answer is not it?

Comment: pretty much - didn't saw your answer before